# Where is udp header added to data in the kernel code

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, udp

I'm coding a new UDP based protocol in the kernel so I just forked the UDP code to get a head start. I need some new fields in the header struct other than the existing ones. I created a new struct for this but I'm at a loss regarding where this struct is initialized to prepend to the data while sending out a udp frame by the udp_sendmsg function(which I copied from the udp code).

To be clear, I just want to change the header that udp_sendmsg() places before the data. So it should be enough to know where in the kernel code the header and data are combined.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't mention which kernel in particular but `udp_sendmsg` points to Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IPv4 a good entry point is [`net/ipv4/udp.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/udp.c#L874)

```
static int udp_send_skb(struct sk_buff *skb, struct flowi4 *fl4)
{
    [...]
    * Create a UDP header
    */
    uh = udp_hdr(skb);
    uh->source = inet->inet_sport;
    uh->dest = fl4->fl4_dport;
    uh->len = htons(len);
    uh->check = 0;
```

Pay particular attention to `udp_hdr` which merely returns a memory location into the skbuff.

```
static inline struct udphdr *udp_hdr(const struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    return (struct udphdr *)skb_transport_header(skb);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd then like to create a similar function say net_protocol_hdr() which can return a pointer of the type struct new_protocol. I've already defined struct new_protocol in my header file and will include this header in file containing the definition for the function new_protocol_hdr. But then, how will the extra space for the new header fields be allocated in the skbuff?

Comment: @GauravSuman I think you're veering into a different question altogether, off-topic here.